# How can I make all my docker containers use my proxy?

Tags: proxy, docker

I am running docker on Debian Jessie which is behind a corporate proxy. To be able to download docker images, I need to add the following to my `/etc/defaults/docker`

```
http_proxy="http://localhost:3128/"
```

I can confirm that this works.

However, in order to be able to access the interwebz from within my container, I need to start all sessions with `--net host` and then setup these env variables:

```
export http_proxy=http://localhost:3128/
export https_proxy=https://localhost:3128/
export ftp_proxy=${http_proxy}
```

Ideally, I would like for the container to not need the host network, and not to know about the proxy (i.e. all outbound calls to port 20, 80, 443 in the container go via the host's proxy port). Is that possible?

Failing that, is it possible to have a site setup, which will ensure that these env variables are set locally but never exported as part of an image? I know I can pass these things with `--env http_proxy=...` etc, but that's clunky. I want it to work for all users on the system without having to use aliases.

(Disclaimer: I asked this on https://superuser.com/posts/890196 but the home for `docker` questions is a little ambiguous at the moment).

Comment: have you tried setting the environment variables correctly in the docker container?    localhost isn't localhost in a docker container without --net.  It should be:     http://[ip-address-or-name-of-host:3128/

Comment: @user2105103 I don't think you understand what I'm asking. The proxy works, I want it to work without having to go through these hoops.

Comment: Exactly.   Have you tried with normal networking and specifying the proxy correctly?    You know docker by default creates a whole separate subnet/bridge?

Comment: The http_proxy setup you described above only affects the docker daemon.   Not sure how to propagate this down to the running containers.   Doesn't really belong 'inside' the container definition IMO.

Comment: Propagating to the container is exactly what I'm asking for, or at the very least, a way to script the `--env` setting for the entire host.

Comment: Looking for a similar solution for Docker EE for Windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See [Proxy all the Containers](http://silarsis.blogspot.nl/2014/03/proxy-all-containers.html):

> Host server runs a container running a proxy (squid, in this case) that can do transparent proxying. That container has some iptables rules that NAT traffic into the proxy server - this means that container needs to run in privileged mode.
>
> Host server also contains (and here's the magic) ip route table entries that re-route all traffic from any container but the proxy that was destined for port 80, through the proxy container.
>
> That last bit essentially means that for port 80 traffic, the route from container to the rest of the world goes through the proxy container - giving it the chance to NAT and transparent proxy.

https://github.com/silarsis/docker-proxy